# Module build failed: Error: Duplicate plugin/preset detected

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, babeljs

I am new to node packages, and I am trying to build the packages. I spent my whole day finding out what might be the issue, but I cannot sort it out. Below is my `package.json` file. If anyone can let me know why I am facing a duplicate plugin/preset error, I will really appreciate it.

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production-noprogress": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@ungap/url-search-params": "^0.1.2",
    "@vimeo/player": "^2.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "2.1.27",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.8",
    "bugsnag-sourcemap-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.7",
    "countup.js": "^1.9.3",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.47",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "img-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "intl-tel-input": "^12.1.10",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-toast-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.0",
    "laravel-mix": "2.1.14",
    "metismenu": "^2.7.8",
    "modernizr": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.4.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "nouislider": "^10.0.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "object.entries": "^1.0.4",
    "outdated-browser-rework": "^2.9.0",
    "pace-progress": "^1.0.2",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "0.8.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "promise": "^7.1.1",
    "scrollreveal": "3.4.0",
    "slick-carousel": "1.6.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.24.4",
    "trix": "^1.0.0",
    "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.20",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "urijs": "^1.17.0",
    "v-img": "^0.2.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.1.0-beta.2",
    "vue": "^2.2.4",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-infinite-scroll": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-l-carousel": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^11.1.4",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.2.4",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "weakmap-polyfill": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "less": "^3.0.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

**babelrc file**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "last 1 version",
            "> 1%",
            "ie >= 11"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import"
  ]
}
```

**Error**

> ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/signup_a/register.js Module build
> failed: Error: Duplicate plugin/preset detected. If you'd like to use
> two separate instances of a plugin, they need separate names, e.g.
>
> plugins: [
> ['some-plugin', {}],
> ['some-plugin', {}, 'some unique name'],
> ]

Comment: What is your Babel config?

Comment: i have added it now, please check it.

Comment: Do you have any Babel config inside your webpack config? Something in one of your configs is duplicated

Comment: i didn't get it. can you let me know which file should i show?

Comment: i have 2 files webpack.mix.js and webpack.mix.signupa.js

Comment: I don't know anything about `laravel` and didn't notice the `--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`. What are your two `mix` files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228176/discussion-between-naveed-ali-and-loganfsmyth).

Comment: Can you post what's in ./resources/assets/js/signup_a/register.js?

Answer (score 0):

Update your package.json to the following, run npm install, then run your command.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.8",
        "@ungap/url-search-params": "^0.2.2",
        "@vimeo/player": "^2.15.3",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
        "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "3.1.0",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.18",
        "bugsnag-sourcemap-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.8",
        "countup.js": "^2.0.7",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
        "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.49",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "img-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.13",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "jquery-toast-plugin": "^1.3.2",
        "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
        "laravel-mix": "6.0.25",
        "less": "^4.1.1",
        "less-loader": "^10.0.1",
        "metismenu": "^3.0.7",
        "modernizr": "^3.11.7",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
        "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
        "nouislider": "^15.2.0",
        "numeral": "^2.0.6",
        "object.entries": "^1.1.4",
        "outdated-browser-rework": "^3.0.1",
        "pace-progress": "^1.0.2",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.2",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
        "promise": "^8.1.0",
        "scrollreveal": "4.0.9",
        "slick-carousel": "1.8.1",
        "sweetalert2": "^11.0.19",
        "trix": "^1.3.1",
        "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.28",
        "underscore": "^1.13.1",
        "urijs": "^1.19.7",
        "v-img": "^0.2.0",
        "vee-validate": "^3.4.11",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-flatpickr-component": "^8.1.7",
        "vue-infinite-scroll": "^2.0.2",
        "vue-l-carousel": "^1.1.0",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2",
        "weakmap-polyfill": "^2.0.4"
    }
}
```